# Best way optimize pairings (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am trying to optimize the pairings between two sets of data ('A' & 'B'). I have created a Pandas DataFrame with all possible combinations of the pairs, plus some defining characteristics (`pre_optimized = pd.DataFrame(possible_pairs`):

```
A  B     C    D
1  a   23.05  2
1  b  100.00  4
1  c   15.12  7
2  a   50.37  5
2  d   72.65  6
2  c   42.00  1
```

I would like an output of the optimal pairings (`post_optimized = pd.DataFrame(optimal_pairs`) such that:

```
maximize(post_optimized['C'].sum())
for x in post_optimized['A'].unique():
     10 <= post_optimized[post_optimized['A']==x]['D'].sum()
```

I would like the output DataFrame to look something like the above, but with just those pairings that were deemed 'optimal' based on the constraints:

```
A  B     C    D
1  a   23.05  2
1  b  100.00  4
2  d   72.65  6
2  c   42.00  1
```

I'm fairly certain I will need to use `scipy.optimize`, but I'm not sure where to start...

Any pointers would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add also expected output for this pre_optimized data frame?

Comment: Just added an example output. Alternatively to this, I would even be fine with just having column 'A' and 'B' in the output df. I can backtrack to get the other data I need from there.

Comment: Why do you want to use `scipy.optimize'? What I understand from you example is that you only want to filter the DataFrame containing all possible pairs. Or are you trying to avoid the creation of all possible pairs in the first place?